# Using npm with Cordova / facedetector

Tags: cordova, npm, cordova-plugins, node-modules, face-detection

I am new to **Cordova** and recently I am trying to create some face detector features for mobile with **Cordova**. I did use the **ezarfacedetector** from **ezAR** which is a plugin mainly for **Cordova**. However I am facing some issue with the hardware part as some phone unable to use that feature. Different phone will produce a different outcome.

Later I found out that https://www.npmjs.com have many similiar facedetector plugins but I am not sure whether npm plugin works with **Cordova**.

So my question is that whether **Cordova** supports npm plugins? If not, do you guys mind share some idea how to I create a facedetector for the phone which able to detect human face with the optional of getting data after detecting (without using any APIs).

Some example like this: [https://www.faceplusplus.com/face-detection/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeCbT.png)

Comment: I think if you dont want to use any apis it could be a problem due to phone limitations. Secondly cordova is using npm to install packages but they must be written specially to cordova to be able to use them in some cases

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat Yea so far I tried the ezAR plugin which is spec for cordova, however it seems not stable as some device cant use it (different as in android version). So i am looking for alternative, but seems like there are very little resources out there.